# Mapping rowname of dataframe to column value of other dataframe with different length?

Tags: r, dataframe, mapping

I have a dataframe `df`

```
        col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
row1     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
row2     0.0     0.4     0.4     0.0     0.0
row3     0.5     1.2     0.4     0.3     0.8
row4     3.3     1.4     1.4     1.0     6.3
row5     0.0     0.2     0.0     0.0     0.0
row6     0.8     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.2
```

and a dataframe `mapping`

```
rowname mapped_name
row1    a
row2    a
row3    a
row5    b
row6    c
```

and I want to get

```
        col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    mapped_name
row1     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0    a
row2     0.0     0.4     0.4     0.0     0.0    a
row3     0.5     1.2     0.4     0.3     0.8    a
row4     3.3     1.4     1.4     1.0     6.3    NA
row5     0.0     0.2     0.0     0.0     0.0    b
row6     0.8     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.2    c
```

Because they are different length when I do `df$mapped_name <- df[mapping$rowname == rownames(df),]$mapped_name` I get

```
character(0)
Warning message:
In mapping$rowname == rownames(df) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 1):

We can `match` the row names of 'df' with 'rowname' column of 'mapping' dataset, use that numeric index to get the corresponding 'mapped_name'

```
df$mapped_name <- mapping$mapped_name[match(row.names(df), mapping$rowname)]

df
#     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 mapped_name
#row1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0           a
#row2  0.0  0.4  0.4  0.0  0.0           a
#row3  0.5  1.2  0.4  0.3  0.8           a
#row4  3.3  1.4  1.4  1.0  6.3        <NA>
#row5  0.0  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0           b
#row6  0.8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2           c
```

Comment: @NiekdeKlein  It is a vector output, so you don't need a `,`

Comment: ahh sorry for me it didn't work without the `,` because I had `mapping[match(row.names(df), mapping$rowname)]$mapped_name`, overlooked the difference

Comment: @NiekdeKlein  In your version, you were subsetting the whole `dataset` so the `,` is needed, and only later the column was selected.